# Angular 2 - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: laravel, angular, cors

When trying to make API Calls from my Angular 2 App to my API, I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/myAPI/public/api/v1/auth/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 422.
```

I've been checking every single question on the web and anything releated to CORS, nothing solved my problem!

My **Laravel API** running on port 80. (localhost)

My **angular 2 app** running on port 3000. (localhost:3000)

- I've been trying to enable cors in Laravel side with Cors middleware
- The API calls are **working** using chrome web security off. The first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709790/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource) solves the problem, But I really want to stop using the CMD and unsecured chrome version everytime im testing my app.
- Using chrome extension POSTMAN API calls to my API are working.

So.. What's wrong? Why my Angular 2 app cant get records from my API?

Comment: Your servers CORS configuration is not correct. Hard to provide more information from the information you provided.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer What information do you need? And when you say servers you mean the API or the apache (i'm using xampp web server)

Comment: Your server CORS configuration. This issue is not Angular related.

Comment: when you say servers you mean the API or the apache itselef (i'm using xampp web server)?

Comment: The server that processes the failing response.

Comment: You are right @GünterZöchbauer, i configured my server itself and now everything works great. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. seem like need to configure apache for it.

i'm using xampp webserver, and I had to edit my httpd.conf as explained [here](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html) to solve this.

Added this line:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:3000"
```

solved my problem.

Restarting apache is neccessary.

Comment: i am using ubuntu then how to solve this issue . i hope you help me thanks

Comment: nice but its take time to find files but Finally i got it:
https://therichpost.com/question/angular-6-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

Answer (score 1):

Open chrome inspect tool, switch to `Network` tab and inspect the request Angular2 sent.

In `Headers`->`Response Headers`,  check whether there is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` (I bet not)

If you are building an API, the easiest workaround is to add

```
if (Request::is("api/*")) {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, If-Modified-Since, Cache-Control, Pragma");
}
```

in the beginning of `routes.php`, using a Middleware would be a better approach, but make sure it is working properly and adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the response header.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Add this middleware in your express app
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
res.header('access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've been trying to enable cors in Laravel side with Cors middleware

Have you registered routes to handle `OPTIONS` requests?

If you simply add middleware to existing `GET` and `POST` routes, and the browser is making an `OPTIONS` request, the middleware is never reached.